# mail use gpg encryption

Tags: scripts, mail, gnupg

I would like to send emails encrypted with gpg from a shell script.
Is there any way to send emails with `gpg`? Or encrypt them using `mail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
echo "Your message" | gpg -ea -r "Recipient name" | mail -s "Subject" recipient@example.com
```

`Recipient name` must to be is in your gpg keyring.

Source: [How can I send gpg encrypted mail automatically from the linux command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/188493/how-can-i-send-gpg-encrypted-mail-automatically-from-the-linux-command-line)

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm getting the following error. Is there any way to suppress it? `--yes` doesn't work.
`It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.`

Comment: @MeinAccount As I said: is that person in your gpg keyring? If not, use `gpg --gen-key` to generate a key for that person. See `man gpg` for more info.

Comment: Yes. I searched for the person and pressed his number.

Comment: @MeinAccount *...pressed his number*?!? It should be his (real) name.

Comment: `gpg --list-keys` lists the person. So I guess he was successfully imported.

Comment: @MeinAccount What is the output of `gpg --list-keys | grep uid` command?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11031/discussion-between-meinaccount-and-radu-rdeanu)